# Como corrigir o erro System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Minha aplicação que gerencia **Cursos** está com esse erro **O item de modelo passado para o dicionário é do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1 [MeuProjeto.Models.Curso] ", mas este dicionário requer um item de modelo do tipo' System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1 [MeuProjeto .Models.AlunoCurso] '**. O que acontece é que eu tenho um `View` que retorna para o **aluno** os cursos que ele está inscrito, e nessa lista tem um botão que é **habilitado** assim que o **administrador** *aprova* o aluno em um **curso**, mas quando eu `debugo` dá esse **erro** acima.

**Minha Action**

```
public ActionResult MeusCursos()
    {
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno != null)
        {
            //O ERRO no DEBUG cai aqui nessa linha.
            return View("MeusCursos", aluno.AlunoCursos.Select(ac => ac.Curso).ToList());
        }

        return View();
    }
```

**Minha View**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.AlunoCurso>

@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Meus Cursos</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Aprovado?
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aprovado)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @if (item.Aprovado == false)
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Pendente de Aprovação" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-default" disabled="disabled" data-id="@item.Id" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @*<a href="@Url.Action("GerarPDF", "AlunoCursos")"> <input type="submit" value="Emitir Declaração" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-success" enable="enable" /> </a>*@
                            <a href="~/AlunoCursos/GerarPDF?id=@item.Id" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".cursos").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MeusCursos/",
                    data: { id: $(this).data("id") },
                    success: function () {
                        $(this).attr("enable", "enable");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está criando uma nova lista de `Cursos` e não de `AlunoCurso` com essa linha:

```
return View("MeusCursos", aluno.AlunoCursos.Select(ac => ac.Curso).ToList());
```

Dentro do seu `.Select` você pega apenas os cursos e retorna como uma nova lista é ai que está seu problema, pois na sua `View` você definiu seu **@model** como:

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.AlunoCurso>
```

Para solucionar isso você precisa remover o `.Select(ac => ac.Curso)` ou trocar o **@model** para `@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>` e adaptar seu código da tela.

Comment: Então @Maicon, é porque na minha tabela de associação **AlunoCurso** tem os campos **AlunoId**, **CursoId** e **Aprovado**. Eu preciso pegar o campo **Aprovado** dessa tabela e listar os cursos.

Comment: e qual o problema em retornar **AlunoCurso**  ?

Comment: Deu certo @Maicon, eu tinha alterado o código no lugar errado. Posso falar com você via chat?

Comment: Sim podemos, vamos lá

Comment: Chama aí no Chat @Maicon, ainda não sei como chamar!

Comment: [Vamos continuar essa discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25272/discussion-between-novato-and-maicon-carraro)